# How do you test Collection.allow( ) functions that rely on the user ID?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js

Given the following collection and access control defintion

```
class TasksCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
  insert (task, callback) {
    const doc = _.extend({}, task, {
      createdOn: new Date(),
      owner: this.userId
    })
    super.insert(doc, callback)
  }
}

export const Tasks = new TasksCollection('tasks')

// Simple checks to ensure that the user is logged in before making changes.
Tasks.allow({
  insert: (userId, doc) =>=> !!userId,
  update: (userId, doc, fields, modifier) => !!userId,
  remove: (userId, doc) => !!userId
})
```

How would you test to ensure that it works using Mocha/Chai/Sinon?  This is what I have tried.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { resetDatabase } from 'meteor/xolvio:cleaner';
import { assert, expect } from 'chai'
import { Tasks } from '/imports/api/tasks'
import sinon from 'sinon'

describe('collection test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    resetDatabase()
  })
  it('can see a collection', () => {
    assert(Tasks, 'unable to see sample collection')
  })
  it('can query an empty collection', () => {
    expect(Tasks.find({}).fetch()).to.be.empty
  })
  it('fails to add to a collection when the user is not logged in', (done) => {
    expect(Tasks.find({}).fetch()).to.be.empty
    Tasks.insert({
      text: 'hello world'
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('expected', error) // this is also a 404
      assert(error)
      done()
    })
  })

  describe('logged in', () => {
    let sandbox
    beforeEach(() => {
      sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
      sandbox.stub(Meteor, 'userId').returns(42)
    })
    afterEach(() => {
      sandbox.restore()
    })
    it('can add to a collection', (done) => {
      expect(Tasks.find({}).fetch()).to.be.empty
      Tasks.insert({
        text: 'hello world'
      }, (error, _id) => {
        console.log(error)
        assert(!error)
        const results = Tasks.find({}).fetch()
        expect(results).to.have.lengthOf(1)
        expect(results[0].defaultValue).to.equal(42)
        expect(results[0]._id).to.equal(_id)
        expect(results[0].createdOn).to.not.be.undefined
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

UPDATE: But I get a 404 error when calling the server.

The `insecure` package is already removed.

UPDATE: I am only testing on the client for now as the authorization can only be done from a client call.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you allow or deny action for particular collection. It will be always allowed on server side. In order to test it you need to execute this test on client side.

Comment: Yup realized that but on the client side it does not work as expected too.  https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-do-you-test-collection-allow-functions-that-rely-on-the-user-id/22543/4

Comment: That's really strange behaviour. Looks like Meteor's bug. Probably, you should consider using methods or validated methods.